# Xcode showing missing files that are not present in the folder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, github, path

I run into an issue while cloning a project from GitHub (https://github.com/DawidBazan/Cryptfolio/tree/develop) that I wanted to work on. I installed all the pods and opened the .xcworkspace file, however when I tried to run the app I got a build error like this:

`error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/mateusz/Cryptfolio/Cryptofolio/Constants.swift' (in target 'Cryptofolio' from project 'Cryptofolio')`

I looked online for solutions and know that sometimes xCode cannot locate files and their path has to be set manually, however this time, the file it is referring to in the error (Constants.swift) is not in the files of the repo from GitHub. I also looked in the files on the git repo itself online, however this file never existed there either.

Below I attach a screenshot of the missing file in xCode and the folder in Finder. Does anyone know what the issue might be? How does xCode come up with a file that is not in the folder to begin with?

I would very much appreciate any help, that’s the only error I get while building the app.

[A screenshot of my workspace with the error and the finder tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaDCf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, looks like your Xcode project has a reference to `Constants.swift` but cannot find an actual file in the repository.

In fact, seems like the file is [ignored in git](https://github.com/DawidBazan/Cryptfolio/blob/5df469278695fff3e996dc9cffdf4ad1b99cbace/.gitignore#L84).

Assuming from the file name `Constants.swift`, looks like it was generated from code-generator (or it can be a secret file which author did not want to publish).

You should find some more info by looking into the libraries that was installed with [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/) or by asking the repository owner.